# Oracle SQL-Query resolve

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
eno   name        loc       flag
1    penchal      pune      old
2    penchal      mumbai    current
3    srinivas     hyd       curent
4    mahesh       chenai    current
```

I want out put like this:

```
Name       oldlocation   newlocation
penchal    pune          mummbai
srinivas   null          hyd
mahesh     null          chennai
```

Could you please help me in this how to write query for this scenario in oracle sql;
Looking for reply

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'old' THEN loc ELSE NULL END) AS oldlocation,
        MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'current' THEN loc ELSE NULL END) AS newlocation
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
     , MAX(DECODE(flag,'old',loc))     oldlocation
     , MAX(DECODE(flag,'current',loc)) newlocation
FROM   tableName
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: This might solve the problem, but can you explain what the query is doing.  Perhaps this will help the original questioner in the future.

Comment: The use of max is because it takes the maximum value and display in the same row for the user as required, decode will work like case statement

Comment: So this is the same as John Woo's answer but with `decode` instead of `case`.